# Change Jenkins default 'Build Status' settings

Tags: jenkins

I was wondering if it is possible to change the built-in build statuses that are reported by Jenkins via email (i.e. Still Failing, Failure, etc..)?  I was looking into the groovy post build plugin, but I can't seem to get the code to change the build status.

Here is my simple code:

```
if(manager.logContains(".*xyz.*")) {
      manager.buildSuccess()
}
```

Also, if someone could post where I can learn more about using Jenkins w/groovy to access Jenkins configuration settings, that would be great.  I search the web but did not find anything to useful.

Thanks for any help,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

For changing status, you may like to try the [Jenkins Text Finder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the E-mail messages i would suggest the [E-Mail-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)